# How to access inner json property value while ignoring outer property key?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Below code :

```
import json

j = json.loads(" {\"id123\":{\"test\" : 1} } ")

j
```

renders :

```
{'id123': {'test': 1}}
```

I'm attempting to access the property test while ignoring the outer property id.

This can be achieved using :

```
j['id123']['test']
```

which returns 1

But as I do not know ahead of time what value the key will be ( in this case it's id123 ) is there a generic way to access the value of property `test` while omitting the property key `id123` ?

Comment: How could there be? You could do it through trial and error by iterating the keys but, since the structure of any JSON response is in the mind of the creator, how can it be standardised?

Comment: `j.values()[0]['test']` would work for your specific example.

Comment: `list(j.values())[0]['test']`

Comment: are you looking for the value of the specific key `test`? or the position that `test` is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume your use case correctly, you want to see the values for the key `test`? Given your current structure - I think using [`items()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_items.htm) could be a solution.

```
for k,v in j.items():
    if 'test' in v.keys():
        print(v.values())

#output is a 'dict_values' type. If you need in another format, that can be done too
dict_values([1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can us the **.keys()** method to find the key of your JSON

**Example**:

```
import json

j = json.loads(" {\"id123\":{\"test\" : 1} } ")

print j.keys()
print j.keys()[0]
print j[j.keys()[0]]['test']
```

**Result**:

```
[u'id123']
id123
1
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this works but, regardless, throw a list into the mix. This might work for a specific example but it's useless _a priori_.

Comment: @roganjosh; This solution is only for the OP current situation/problem. Not a general solution.

Comment: "But as I do not know ahead of time what value the key will be...". There is no base solution.

Comment: In other words, the question seems general and you provided a specific answer. As soon as there's a small change, your approach is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this to avoid outer key and get all values inside inner dict**

```
import json

j = json.loads(" {\"id123\":{\"test\" : 1} } ")
for i in j.values():
    for x in i:
        print (i[x])  #your expected output
```